# How do you use dot referencing (for the data frame) and groups in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following example data:

```
  groups a b
1      A 1 1
2      A 2 1
3      A 3 1
4      B 4 2
5      B 5 2
6      B 6 2
7      C 7 3
8      C 8 3
9      C 9 3

df <- data.frame(groups = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3), 
                           a = 1:9, 
                           b = rep(1:3, each = 3))
```

I wish to do the following, except using `colSums`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% summarise(min_group = min(c(sum(a), sum(b))), .by = groups)

# Output:
  groups min_group
1      A         3
2      B         6
3      C         9
```

Using dot referencing, I get an unexpected result:

```
df %>% summarise(min_group = min(colSums(.[, c('a', 'b')])), .by = groups)
# Output:
  groups min_group
1      A        18
2      B        18
3      C        18
```

that is, it looks like the groups are not being applied.

Comment: `colSums` is internally converting to a matrix, which is not a good idea for efficiency at scale. Just use `tmp_df_dplyr %>% group_by(groups) %>% summarise_all(sum) %>% mutate(min_sum = pmin(a, b))`.

Comment: @alistaire - so to get the min of those sums, would something like `tmp_df_dplyr %>%
    group_by(groups) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(sum)) %>%
    group_by(groups) %>%
    summarise(mincol = min(a,b))` be required?

Comment: or with reshaping, `tmp_df_dplyr %>% gather(var, val, a:b) %>% group_by(groups, var) %>% summarise(sum_val = sum(val)) %>% summarise(min_sum = min(sum_val))`

Comment: so it looks like to get around this one needs to use a `summarise_at` operation. That is a little bit inconvenient.

Comment: and the underlying root of the problem seems to be that any reference to variables using `.` is not compatible with groups.

Comment: I updated the example from the question to make it easier to understand for SEO people, as the previous example dataframe had a lot of duplicate rows and made understanding what was actually going on needlessly difficult. Feel free to roll back if you think this isn't in the spirit of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisiting this, you can do the following using `do` to incorporate dot `.` notation for the left-sided data through the pipe. The original post used a separate `group_by` statement before `summarise`. This would then become:

```
df %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  do(summarise(., min_group = min(colSums(.[, c('a', 'b')]))))
```

A more recent tidyverse approach would be to use `pick` to select column names, and `.by` argument for the grouping. `pick` provides a way to easily select a subset of columns from data, using `select` semantics while inside a "data-masking" function like `summarise`.

```
df %>%
  summarise(min_group = min(colSums(pick(a, b))), .by = groups)
```

**Output**

```
  groups min_group
1      A         3
2      B         6
3      C         9
```